# While I am trying to delete this account it can't

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

I am getting error while deleting account of Stack Overflow. When I delete my account and again I am trying to log-in it successfully login. So help me how to delete this account?

Comment: I think error of stackoverflow team.. we can say bug

Comment: I think you are re-login before the account got deleted by team. Account doesnt delete immediately it normally takes time.

Comment: Did you go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete an account on most sites, there is, usually a grace period to reactivate the account. Usually reactivating such accounts involves logging back into the account. So re-logging into the account is a flawed way to test if the account has been deleted.

A better way is to copy the url of your account profile and then search that after you have, successfully, deleted your account. It will show if the account is active.

As I can by your inactive username link you account has been deleted. Hence I am addressing a cyber ghost *spooky*. Does this mean I need a seance to get an accepted answer here??? **;-)**

Comment: For the last paragraph: Not necessarily. The question has been migrated, in that case it only means he has no Meta account.